# Firefox wants to update when I am using selenium?

Tags: selenium

Firefox is up to date on my computer but when I use selenium sometimes it messes up my program by saying that I need to or should update. Eventually this window can stop my program from working..is there any way to stop this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If this is on a machine you have access to firefox has a setting that allows you to disable checking for updates which is the easiest way.

If you want to enforce this for all test runs, apparently the following should work:

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.setPreference("app.update.auto", false);
profile.setPreference("app.update.enabled", false);
FirefoxDriver browser = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

Comment: i needed to delete the already downloaded update to prevent Windows 10 from prompting me to install on every driver launch. Mine was in ```%APPDATA%\Local\Mozilla\updates```  This seems to be working with the new Options Object which is preferred in selenium 4.3.0.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the accepted answer:

1.) You can change the two autoupdate settings he mentioned in about:config of your FF profile, if you are reusing the same FF profile each time you run tests

2.) There are additional settings (e.g. outdated plugins can cause FF to update, extension options to autoupdate need to be turned off) which may help: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-stop-firefox-making-automatic-connections

3.) After doing both 1 and 2 above if you still have issues, deleting updater.exe from the Mozilla program folder (C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\ or the x86 location) *might* do the trick but could also, as deleting a file from the programs folder can do anytime, cause unexpected problems