# Stopping auto update of Mozilla Firefox

Tags: firefox, selenium

Our automation suite and application runs fine in FF 35, however it gets auto updated to latest version and our execution fails, we could not change all selenium jars and our application, is there a way to stop this auto update? 
Things tried:
1. Disabled auto update in options menu.
2. Toggled all update values to 'false' by going to "about:config"

And every time I try to uninstall latest version it forces me to restart the system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When installing Firefox, choose the customize radio button instead of default installation may be in 2nd or 3rd screen of the installation wizard and `uncheck`  Mozilla/Firefox `maintenance service`. It will certainly work.

plus:

```
app.update.auto - false
app.update.enabled - false
app.update.silent - false
```

in firefox configuration

plus:

Disable auto update from:
`Tools->Options->Advanced->Update->` select `never check for update`

Good luck

Answer (score 3):

I think the reason your solution did not work is because you updated *your* profile, rather than profile which is used  when selenium tests are running. So what you need is either:

1. Create a profile that will not update and use it statically with selenium (as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30174244/how-do-i-disable-firefoxs-auto-update-globally-via-cli))
2. Or, use a custom profile, for which you disable auto-update every time you start Firefox, (as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20893070/firefox-wants-to-update-when-i-am-using-selenium))