# Fetching any page using Python Selenium Firefox Webrower is fetching mozilla.net page also

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am using simple program to fetch

```
https://ipinfo.io
```

using proxy configuration in python / selenium / firefox webdriver

```
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference("network.proxy.type", 1)
profile.set_preference("network.proxy.http", proxy )
profile.set_preference("network.proxy.http_port", port)
profile.set_preference("network.proxy.https", proxy)
profile.set_preference("network.proxy.https_port", port)
profile.set_preference("network.proxy.ssl", proxy)
profile.set_preference("network.proxy.ssl_port", port)
profile.set_preference("network.proxy.socks", proxy)
profile.set_preference("network.proxy.socks_port", port)

driver = webdriver.Firefox(profile)
url = "https://ipinfo.io"
driver.get(url)
driver.quit()
```

In proxy log I see

```
CONNECT tracking-protection.cdn.mozilla.net
CONNECT firefox.settings.services.mozilla.com
CONNECT firefox.settings.services.mozilla.com
```

What is all this prefetches before the actual url is called ? I don't want these to happen, so what am I suppose to configure ? I even tried

```
profile.set_preference("browser.startup.homepage_override.mstone", "ignore")
profile.set_preference("startup.homepage_welcome_url.additional", "about:blank")
```

but still it didn't help and continues to hit those Mozilla URLs

I don't want to overload proxy with additional traffic. What is the way out to this issue ?

Comment: Use incognito ?

Comment: what is the preference setting for that ?

Comment: This might help with at least one of those unwanted connections. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20893070/firefox-wants-to-update-when-i-am-using-selenium

Answer (score 0):

```
from selenium import webdriver

firefox_profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
firefox_profile.set_preference("browser.privatebrowsing.autostart", True)

driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=firefox_profile)
```

Use incognito mode

Comment: added this but still showing all those tracking log in squid

Comment: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-stop-firefox-making-automatic-connections

Comment: it seems this cannot be disabled

Comment: see the last point you have to explicitly set to route all traffic to localhost for that address